# where can I find the active alonzo-test configuration json files

Tags: stake-pool

I am not able to fully understand where the active configuration files are located for alonzo test and main net.

I found this link from doing the alonzo-test exercises:

https://hydra.iohk.io/build/7189190/download/1/index.html

but this seems to be for 1.28, and I am currently running 1.29, and I am not able to connect.

Is there a way to know what build I should use for 1.29 configuration?

I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 3):

In this guide is updated (using 7191656)
https://developers.cardano.org/docs/get-started/running-cardano/

So at the end just add
`testnet-alonzo-genesis.json` or `mainnet-alonzo-genesis.json`

Comment: wow, thanks a lot! I was reading outdated docs.